# Using web scraping to recive all Twitter followers

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, twitter, node-fetch

I want to create giveaways which require the participants to follow the twitter account of the giveaway creator.
My first idea was to use the Twitter API (endpoint: "/2/users/:id/followers"). This works fine for me however I always run into rating limits. The API allows me to send 15 requests every 15 minutes and returns a maximum of 1000 users per request. Since many accounts have more then 15000 followers and since many request happen at the same time (many users want to participate in a giveaway) this solution is not suitable for me.
My secound idea was to use web scraping instead (e.g Node Fetch). [I was following along this tutoria](https://geekflare.com/web-scraping-in-javascript/): However doing so I always run into the issue that Twitter uses random strings to name their html elements. You can see in the picture there is no defined class to grap the elements.

So my main question is how can I access these element ?
[Random Follower of my Twitter Account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHXUY.png)

I also have a follow up question regarding the effictivness of this method. Assuming I have multiple people who want to particpate in a short amount of time (e.g 10 people in 5 minutes) and they all need to follow a big twitter account (e.g 100k followers).
Is it efficent to scrape all 100k followers each time or should I instead try to fetch the 100k followers once, safe them to my database and use my database to check for each user later ?

As a side note, I am using node.js and node-fetch, however I have no problems to switch the framework. In addition I think the grabbing of the element as well as the performance should be universal.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

They're going to detect your servers excessive calls. There is a Twitter Developer Portal where you can request elevated access which may raise the limits for you.

https://developer.twitter.com